# Android:Sending data periodically

Tags: android

I have tried to send data over bluetooth whenever I slide the `SeekBar` using SeekBar's `onProgressChanged()` method and every thing works fine.

When I tried to do the same using accelerometer's `onSensorChanged()` method,i.e when I write code for transmission in `onSensorChanged()` method,no date is being written to the Bluetooth

I guess the accelerometer's `onSensorChanged()` method is getting called tooo frequently(like 1000 times per second).I want to reduce the speed of writing data to the bluetooth.

Is there a way to transmit data periodically? For example 1 reading for every 3 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can set the sensitivity of the sensor, or min change before the listener is called again (a bit like with finding your location).

If that fails, you can always put in a little check yourself based on the info to change a min amount, or using the System time to calculate a difference with the last time you allowed it to write data, and check that for whatever time you want as delay.